# ImageView in custom TableViewCell doesn't load with SDWebImage

Tags: sdwebimage

I have a TableViewController. I am using custom cells. Cell has 2 labels and imageView.

I want to load images asynchronously by SDWebImage.

The code is:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"NewsCell";
    NewsCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[NewsCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                   reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    News* new = [_news objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.titleLabel.text = new.title;
    cell.contentLabel.text = new.content;
    if(new.images.count > 0){
        [cell.imageView setImageWithURL:[Helper pathForBigImage:new.images[0]]];
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Image is not seen in the first load. If I reload, i can see it.

Where am I wrong?

Comment: Have you checked the new.images to see if it has any images at load time?

Comment: yes, it has 2 images. And I control it if(new.images.count > 0)

Comment: Log the URL you get at load from `[Helper pathForBigImage:new.images[0]]` .

Comment: I can see the URL when I log.